# Would Apple allow Kivi Framework in Python in IOS App Store?

Tags: python, ios, iphone

It is said here http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/intro.html?highlight=iphone

> On your computer, you can create apps that run on:
>
> Desktop computer: MacOSX, Linux, Windows.
>
> iOs Devices: iPad, iPhone
>
> Android devices: Tablets, Phones. And any others touch enabled
>
> professional/homebrew devices supporting TUIO.

But would Apple allow ios apps made with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their FAQ page ( http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html#faq ) states that the apps will be accepted. And they have http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/deflectouch/id505729681 as an example, built with kivy.

Comment: Great then. I don't know python but it can be worth learning thanks to kivi